# Using .select, .uniq and .order in PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a one-to-many relationship between the models Organizer and Event.

I want to get the five organizers that most recently has updated an event.

```
    Event.order('updated_at asc').
    where(organizer_id: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]).
    select(:organizer_id).uniq.limit(5)
```

The above code works good in SQLite3 but throws the follwoing error on Heroku in PostgreSQL:

```
for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
```

How do I make the query work in PG, e.g. with the method suggested in the error message?

I would prefer to have a solution that is as much ActiveRecord as possible, not pure SQL, if possible.

Comment: as the error message already states "ORDER BY expression must appear in select list" so put the column that you are ordering on into your select!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are ordering by `updated_at`, but are selecting only `organizer_id`. Postgres requires that fields used in ORDER clauses be in the SELECT clause. You need to add `updated_at` to your `select` list.

In SQL, right now you have:

```
SELECT organizer_id FROM events WHERE ... ORDER BY updated_at asc;
```

You need:

```
SELECT organizer_id, updated_at FROM events WHERE ... ORDER BY updated_at asc;
```

Comment: Do you know how that would translate into a more ActiveRecord-esque query?

Comment: Modify your `select` clause: `select(:organizer_id, :updated_at)`.

Comment: I guess this is the perfect answer (seen by the upvotes), but unfortunately it doesn't help me - giving the select method two parameters makes the the .uniq method unfunctional. :/  The unique aspect here is equally important.. But thank you anyway for your time.

Comment: Simply add a `group(:organizer_id)` clause.